# Birthday users between current date and next 7 days not working with between condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have write a simple query to check birthday between current date and next 7 days which works fine few days before but now its returning 0 result the reason I've found is its searching between 12-29 to 01-05 so I think that's why its not returning here's the query :

```
SELECT `U`.`FirstName`, `U`.`LastName`, `U`.`UserGUID`, `U`.`ProfilePicture`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(U.DOB,'%m-%d') 
BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-29 07:08:01','%m-%d') 
        AND DATE_FORMAT('2016-01-05','%m-%d')
```

Comment: Yes, you should check year as well

Comment: but I need to check birthday not birthdate what about those peoples whose birthday comes before 2015 or 2016 ?

Comment: Please improve your question and add table structure

Answer (score 2):

Change query as:

> ```
>   SELECT `U`.`FirstName`, `U`.`LastName`, `U`.`UserGUID`,
>  `U`.`ProfilePicture` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(U.DOB,'%m-%d') BETWEEN
>  date_format(DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-29 07:08:01','%y-%m-%d'),'%m-%d') AND
>  Date_Format(DATE_FORMAT('2016-01-05','%y-%m-%d'),'%m-%d')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string comparison by `DATE_FORMAT(U.DOB,'%Y%m')`.

`DATE_FORMAT(U.DOB,'%Y%m')` should return dates like: *YYYYMM*. You would also need to change the format of your variables or use the same method on them.

```
SELECT `U`.`FirstName`, `U`.`LastName`, `U`.`UserGUID`, `U`.`ProfilePicture` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(U.DOB,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT('2015-12-29 07:08:01','%Y%m') AND 
DATE_FORMAT(U.DOB,'%Y%m') <= DATE_FORMAT('2016-01-05','%Y%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like below

```
SELECT `U`.`FirstName`, `U`.`LastName`, `U`.`UserGUID`, `U`.`ProfilePicture` WHERE DAY(cast(U.DOB as datetime)) BETWEEN DAY(cast('2015-12-29 07:08:01' as datetime)) AND DAY(cast('2016-01-05' as datetime)) AND 
MONTH(CAST(U.DOB AS DATETIME)) BETWEEN MONTH(CAST('2015-12-29 07:08:01'AS DATETIME)) AND MONTH(CAST('2016-01-05' AS DATETIME))
```